# How to resolve java.lang.NullPointerException in spark dataframe's except operation?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am having two dataframes which contains user ids. I want to take difference of those dataframes, so used `except` as below:

```
df1.except(df2);
```

But getting following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:826)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not getting where is the issue.

I tried to filter out both dataframes with null values also.

**Edit: Schema and Sample Data of both dataframes:**

Schema:

df1.printSchema -

```
root
 |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
```

df2.printSchema

```
root
 |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
```

Data of df1:

```
+--------------------+
|                 uid|
+--------------------+
|               sss12|
|       ushadevi_8512|
|           babu57111|
|       gianchand-199|
|          rju-815423|
```

Data of df2:

```
+--------------------+
|                 uid|
+--------------------+
|        navratn-3131|
|          jaykumar-1|
|      vishwanath-666|
|     dharmendra-5623|
```

Comment: can you please post sample data of both daraframes.

Comment: `except` is not an action. Please add some more code to create a `[mcve]

Comment: @philantrovert I have used show() action then.